# Vertically and Horizontally centering buttons in a div

Tags: html, css

I really need your help,

How can the HTML & CSS markup below be modified such that the buttons that are contained in the Div ("Box D") be centered vertically as well as horizontally?

Here is the HTML & CSS in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main {
    border: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
    width: 800px;
    height: 650px;
}
#boxA {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
}
#boxB {
    height: 573px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
}
#boxC {
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    height: 573px;
    width: 598px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#boxD {
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
    height: 44px;
    text-align: center; 
}
#menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#menu li {
    padding: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#menu li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
    background: rgb(51,153,255);
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.hidden{ display:none; }


.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


input[type="button"] 
{
  cursor:pointer; 
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #fff, inset 0 -0.7em #DDD;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F1F1F1 0%, #E3E3E3 50%, #D0D0D0 100%);
  padding: 3px 6px;
  width: 75px;
}

input[type="button"]:hover 
{
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color: #EAF6FD;
  border: 1px solid #3C7FB1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #fff, inset 0 -0.7em #BEE6FD, 0 0 3px #A7D9F5;
}

input[type="button"][disabled], input[type="button"][disabled]:hover

{
  border: 1px solid #ADB2B5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  cursor:default;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #fff;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menu li").click(function(){ 
        var $li = $(this);
        var selector = $li.data("show");
        $('.item').addClass('hidden');

        $('ul').children().removeClass('selected');

        $(selector).removeClass("hidden");
        $(this).addClass("selected");

        //alert($(this).attr("class").split(' '))
    });

    $("#menu li").eq(0).click();

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="main">

    <div id="boxA"><b>Application Title</b></div>

    <div id="boxB">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li data-show="#1">Menu Item 1</li>
            <li data-show="#2">Menu Item 2</li>
            <li data-show="#3">Menu Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="boxC">

        <div id="1" class="hidden item">
            <b>Content Tab 1</b>
        </div>

        <div id="2" class="hidden item">
            Content Tab 2
        </div>

        <div id="3" class="hidden item">
            Content Tab 3
        </div>

    </div>

        <div id="boxD">

            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
                <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Clear All" class="btn">
                <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Export" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Recall" class="btn" disabled>
            </div>

        </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your #boxD like this:

```
#boxD {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
```

Sample code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menu li").click(function(){ 
        var $li = $(this);
        var selector = $li.data("show");
        $('.item').addClass('hidden');

        $('ul').children().removeClass('selected');

        $(selector).removeClass("hidden");
        $(this).addClass("selected");

        //alert($(this).attr("class").split(' '))
    });

    $("#menu li").eq(0).click();

});
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main {
    border: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
    width: 800px;
    height: 650px;
}
#boxA {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
}
#boxB {
    height: 573px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
}
#boxC {
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    height: 573px;
    width: 598px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#boxD {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
    height: 44px;
    text-align: center; 
}
#menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#menu li {
    padding: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#menu li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
    background: rgb(51,153,255);
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.hidden{ display:none; }


.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


input[type="button"] 
{
  cursor:pointer; 
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #fff, inset 0 -0.7em #DDD;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F1F1F1 0%, #E3E3E3 50%, #D0D0D0 100%);
  padding: 3px 6px;
  width: 75px;
}

input[type="button"]:hover 
{
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color: #EAF6FD;
  border: 1px solid #3C7FB1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #fff, inset 0 -0.7em #BEE6FD, 0 0 3px #A7D9F5;
}

input[type="button"][disabled], input[type="button"][disabled]:hover

{
  border: 1px solid #ADB2B5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  cursor:default;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

    <div id="boxA"><b>Application Title</b></div>

    <div id="boxB">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li data-show="#1">Menu Item 1</li>
            <li data-show="#2">Menu Item 2</li>
            <li data-show="#3">Menu Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="boxC">

        <div id="1" class="hidden item">
            <b>Content Tab 1</b>
        </div>

        <div id="2" class="hidden item">
            Content Tab 2
        </div>

        <div id="3" class="hidden item">
            Content Tab 3
        </div>

    </div>

        <div id="boxD">

            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
                <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Clear All" class="btn">
                <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Export" class="btn" disabled>
                <input type="button" value="Recall" class="btn" disabled>
            </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer! I didn't think to do display: table.

Comment: Thanks. There were already `table-cell` inline style so it seemed the way to go

Answer (score 0):

To center the buttons in their parent `div`, you could do `margin: 0 auto` on the `btn`class. Although, it would probably be better if you created a new CSS class, then assign it to your buttons; you may want to later create other buttons that might not need to be center-aligned to their containers.

Try the following:

Add a class to your CSS.

```
.centeredBtn {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then, on your HTML markup:

```
<input type="button" value="Search" class="btn centeredBtn" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick easily:

```
#boxD {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```